# real part of an analytic function is $\ge0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ be analytic such that $\Re(f)\ge 0$ then

1. $\Im(f)=$ constant
2. $\Im(f)\ge 0$
3. $f=$ constant
4. $\Re(f)=|z|$

what I have done is if $f=u+iv$ then consider, $g(z)=e^{u+iv}$ then $|g|=e^{u}$ as $g$ never vanishes so $g$ must be constant so 3 is correct in my guess. 2 is not necesarily true also 4, please help for rigoriousness.

Comment: Two things that might help:  
Firstly, you need to know the set on which $f$ is analytic (and on which $Re(f)\ge 0$). e.g. is $f$ analytic in all of $\mathbb{C}$?  
Secondly, I think you will find that $|g|=e^{u}$, and not $|g|=e^{|u|}$.

Comment: Dear sir, yes all $\mathbb{C}$ oh that was typo, I am correcting it.

Comment: $G(z) =\frac{1}{f(z)+1}$ is entire and bounded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then here is a sketch solution:

Put $g = e^{-f}$, and consider $|g|= e^{-u}\le 1$, so that $g$ is bounded in all of $\mathbb{C}$. Then use Liouville's Theorem.

Added: Note also that this only proves that $g$ is constant in $\mathbb{C}$, and you will need to do a bit more work (e.g. calculate $g'$) to show that $f$ is constant in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: so $e^{-f}=c$ so $-f'e^{-f}=0$ so $f'=0$ so $f=constant$ am I ryt?

Comment: Yes, that is right.